# Advise with shared code project in a Web project (legacy) with multiple micro sites

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

I have 1 main application (legacy) that has alot of things jumbled in it.

[] MAIN web application

Now we have multiple micro sites that we are building or have built, and I want to clean things up so I want to create a shared project that has common code in it (revolutionary I know!).

Should I create a AppName.Common project in the solution for the Main application, or just a seperate TFS repository altogether?

If it is separate or in the main app's solution, how can I get the main app and micro sites to link to the compiled version of the dll?

Answer (score 1):

This is hard to give an answer to. It really depends on your project and team.

Moving common code into another project within the same solution is what I would think of first and it's a change you can make without disrupting any other team members. Solutions give you a fair bit of flexibility, you could have for example, one solution with everything in, and one solution which only contains site A and its dependencies, and these two solutions can coexist happily.

I can't see a reason to put anything in a separate TFS repo, that would mean the need to constantly update the sites repo with the shared code. I think you need a very good reason to change anything in your TFS setup because I regard TFS as a pain to do anything with.